# Scala: How is instance of Any also instance of Subtypes, Int, Boolean etc

Tags: scala, scala-collections

```
class Parent 
class Child extends Parent

val p = new Parent
val c = new Child

p.isInstanceOf[Parent] // Return true 
p.isInstanceOf[Child] // false, 

c.isInstanceOf[Child] // Return true
c.isInstanceOf[Parent] // true as Child is a subtype of Parent
```

So we have above behaviour. Now from what I have read about Scala yet in my very beginner Scala days, Any is the supertype of all classes. All value types, **Int, Boolean, Double etc are subtypes of** **Any**.

So any value of subtypes like Int, Boolean etc will also be of type Any. But vice versa will not be true.

```
val i: Int = 10
i.isInstanceOf[Int] // true
i.isInstanceOf[Any] // true

val a: Any = 5
a.isInstanceOf[Any] // true. Everything until now, inline with the Parent, Child example above
a.isInstanceOf[Int] // Returns true as well. How? a is of Any type and Int is a Subtype of Any, then how is a value of Any type, also of type Int.
```

Comment: In short, isInstanceOf does not check the declaration type. It checks the underlying object type.

Comment: @texabruce Actually it checks the underlying object **class** not **type**. `isInstsnceOf` is a _runtime_ check, not a _compile-time_ one. In the **JVM** runtime there are not **types** only **classes**. - [this](https://typelevel.org/blog/2017/02/13/more-types-than-classes.html) blog post answer this question more clearly than any of the answers provided so far.

Answer (score 0):

When you write,

```
val s: String = "a sample string"
```

You have 3 very separate things,

1. An `immutable variable` of type `String`.
2. An `identifier` `s` which identifies the above mentioned `variable`.
3. An `instance` of type `String`, the above `variable` refers to this `instance` as `value`.

Now, a `variable` of type `A` can refer to any instance of type `B` as long as `B` is a sub-type of `A`.

So, if you write,

```
val a: Any = "another sample string"
```

You get an `identifier` `a` identifying an `immutable variable` of type `Any` referring to an instance of type `String`.

So, if you check `a.isInstanceOf[String]`, you will get `true` because the instance referred by `a` is of type `String`.